# Why do my Firebase Dynamic Links turn into Branch Dynamic Links?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, branch.io

I created a firebase dynamic link https://eagleeyebuild.page.link/deleteaccount. When I click it on a browser, it takes me to https://eagleeyebuild.app.link/deleteaccount with a branch error page stating **"That link could not be found!"**, same thing in my Xcode console. Why is a Firebase Dynamic link turning into a Branch deep link?